# Bind a Text Block inside a list box with Nested Member

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to get the nested class property value and show it in listbox item. but seems my approach could be wrong.

Here is the XAML of Listbox

```
<ListBox x:Name="lsbQuranData" Grid.Row="2" Foreground="Black" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Width="480">
                <local:SuraWithProgressBar Width="480" SuraNumber ="{Binding Chapter.SuraNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"
                SuraName="{Binding Chapter.SuraTName}" Available="{Binding Available, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
                <Line X1="0" X2="480" Y1="0" Y2="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The classes

```
public class Chapter
{
    private string _suraName, _type, _ename, _tname;
    byte _suraNumber, _ruku;
    Int16 _order, _start, _ayas;

    public string SuraTName
    {
        get { return _tname; }
        set { _tname = value; }
    }

    public Byte SuraNumber
    {
        get { return _suraNumber; }
        set { _suraNumber = value; }
    }
}

public class ChapterSetting
{
    Chapter _chapter;
    string _available;

    public Chapter Chapter
    {
        get { return _chapter; }
        set { _chapter = value; }
    }

    public string Available
    {
        get { return _available; }
        set { _available = value; }
    }
}
```

Data binding for listbox

```
lsbQuranData.ItemsSource = ds.getQuranSuraSetting();
```

the method "getQuranSuraSetting" returns all values that I require, But it cannot bind two fields (SuraName, SuraNumber).

Would it be possible to bind nested class member with listbox item?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and your syntax is correct.  `SuraNumber` isn't a property of the `Chapter` class, though.

Comment: Thanks, It's there, sorry I just cleaned other properties from here and only pasted SuraTName property. these two properties are not binding. (I edited the question)

Comment: Do you bind to `lsbQuranData.ItemsSource` list with type `ObservableCollection<ChapterSettings>`?

Comment: Thanks, basically I was using MVVM to do binding in my user control and I changed that to "Chapter.SuraTName" and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show what is being returned from **ds.getQuranSuraSetting()**.  If it is an `IEnumerable<ChapterSetting>.`

then the XAML should work.

**CODE**

```
<StackPanel Width="480">
    <local:SuraWithProgressBar Width="480" 
                               SuraNumber ="{Binding Chapter.SuraNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               SuraName="{Binding Chapter.SuraTName}" Available="{Binding Available, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
   <Line X1="0" X2="480" Y1="0" Y2="0" 
         VerticalAlignment="Bottom" StrokeThickness="2" 
         Stroke="Black" />
 </StackPanel>
```

You did give us the code for your custom control (SuraWithProgressBar ) so it's hard to tell if you have any errors in your SuraNumber and SuraName properties.

Also, if you are using TextBlocks in your SuraWithProgressBar control, verify that their foreground property is not set to the same color as your page background, or you won't see the bound data

Comment: Thanks Ritscher, I solved it, I added my comment in my question.